# $G$ finite, $P < G$ a Sylow p-subgroup, $N_{G}(P)$ the normalizer is contained in $H < G$, show $N_{G}(H)=H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P<G$ be a Sylow p-subgroup. Let $N_{G}(P)$ be the normalizer of $P$ in $G$. Let $H<G$ be a subgroup containing $N_{G}(P)$. Prove that $N_{G}(H)=H$.

I've been playing around with this for awhile. I've been considering group actions and the fact that $P \leq N_{G}(P) \leq H \leq N_{G}(H)$ but am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that we need only show that $N_G(H) \leq H$. Let $g \in N_G(H)$. Then
$$
gPg^{-1} \subseteq gHg^{-1} = H.
$$
Note that $gPg^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $H$. It is, in fact, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$! Therefore by the Sylow Conjugacy Theorem, $gPg^{-1} = hPh^{-1}$, for some $h \in H$. Then
$$
(g^{-1}h)P(g^{-1}h)^{-1} = P,
$$
so $$g^{-1}h \in N_G(P) \leq H.$$
But that implies that $$g^{-1}h h^{-1} = g^{-1} \in H,$$
so $g \in H$, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very similar to the proof that $N(N(P)) = N(P)$, the normalizer of the normalizer is the normalizer for $P$ a Sylow subgroup.

Comment: @Andrew: The fact that $N_G\left(N_G\left(P\right)\right) = N_G\left(P\right)$ is the particular case of your question for $H = N_G\left(P\right)$. No surprise that the proof is similar.